# What is the average collision duration?

Tags: kinetic-theory-of-gases

So I've been trying to figure this out: What is the average collision duration of a gas in terms of macroscopic variables?

What I have figured out. Whenever two molecules collide they must reach a [potential barrier](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/715232/minimum-energy-required-to-behave-like-a-turning-point) (before behaving like a turning point) of

$$V_{barrier} = \frac{1}{2} \mu v_{rel}^2 \tag1$$

where, $V_{barrier}$ is the height of the potential before behaving as a turning point, $\mu$ is the reduced mass and $v_{rel}$ is the relative velocity. Thus, on average the gas molecule's collisions goes upto a potential height

$$ \langle V_{barrier} \rangle \propto T $$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are basically 2 possible approaches:

Guessing approach, based on typical molecule speed and the supposed size of molecule deformation, that could provide the order of collision lasting interval. 
More precise quantitative evaluation would need the potential energy curve like E_pot=f(r), what may be available for special cases, but not generally.

Comment: There is no clear cut radius of atom and therefore no duration.

Comment: Before you start calculating, you need to define what *exactly* a collision is, when it starts and ends.